# Actualizar esta operacion a php7

Tags: php7

¿Cóomo sería la traducción por así decirlo de este código php que esta en otra versión para la versión numero 7

```
<?php
include('conectar.php');

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mitabla");
$total = 0; // total declarado antes del bucle
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
{
  $total = $total + $row['valor']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
}
echo $total; // Se imprime $total y se realiza la suma
?>
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentado al momento?

Comment: Nada, por eso vino aqui jejeje

Comment: Siempre es necesario que trates algo antes, por ejemplo la doc. [de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) expone como construir consultas mediante las funciones de *mysqli* entonces sugiero trates algo y conforme tengas errores puntuales te ayudaremos

Comment: Hay un ejemplo [justo aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php#example-1609)

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Al final los comentarios que me hicieron me ayudaron bastante con la documentacion correcta de php de migracion de vieja version a nueva version y el resultado fue este.

```
<?php   
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "proyecto");
                            
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT total_price FROM orden");
    $total = 0; // total declarado antes del bucle
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
        $total = $total + $row['total_price']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
     }
     
     echo $total; // Se imprime $total y se realiza la suma

    ?>
```

Comment: Te recomendaría que uses el estilo orientado a objetos. Muchas de las funciones de mysqli son obsoletas, por lo que tu código podría dejar de funcionar en futuras versiones de PHP.